# Recall main function with arguments

Tags: c

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define sleep(x) Sleep(1000 * x)

int checkTime();

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) { 

    char *getFirstArgument = argv[1];
    char *getSecondArgument = argv[2];
    char getCheckTime;

    checkTime(&getCheckTime);

    if(*getFirstArgument != getCheckTime) {
        sleep(1);
        main(*getFirstArgument);
    } else if(*getFirstArgument == getCheckTime && *getSecondArgument == 'r') {
        system("shutdown /r");
    } else if(*getFirstArgument == getCheckTime) {
        system("shutdown /s"); 
    }

    return 0;

}

int checkTime() {

    char getConvertedTime[5] = {};

    SYSTEMTIME localTime;
    GetLocalTime ( &localTime );

    sprintf( getConvertedTime, "%d:%d", localTime.wHour, localTime.wMinute );
    printf( "%s\n", getConvertedTime );

    return 0;

}
```

Hi! I don't know what arguments I need to put when I recall main function, and I really can't find the answer, I know it's exist somewhere. :) And here is the error what show me the MinGW compiler.

```
$ gcc -Wall test.c -o test.exe 
test.c: in function 'main':
test.c:20:3: error: to few arguments to function 'main'
test.c:10:5: note: declared here
```

Sorry for my bad english! Thank you!

Comment: The C standard forbids in principle a program to call `main`. The `main` function should be defined, but not called..

Comment: @Basile: that's C++, not C (unless that changed in C11).

Comment: As you can see, from the prototype main takes an int, and an array of strings (char*), where the int should be the element count of the array

Comment: Does gcc really say "to few arguments"? Surely it says "too few arguments". In which case, you need to learn how to use copy/paste to make sure that you don't post fake error messages. Anyway, what makes you think you can call a function without passing the right number of arguments?

Comment: @David Heffernan, yep, I can make a print screen with this error message :)

Comment: Strange. My version of gcc spells it correctly.

Comment: @Mat: The `main` "function" has been special for aeons, codified as such by ANSI at least (there are environments where it gets called by a special mechanism (think `argc` and `argv` from the caller's point of view) and has to return specially (report to the caller it succeded/failed). In Unixy systems it is typically implemented as a true function called from a stub that does the above glue, but there are no guarantees.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, the `main()` function is prototyped by its definition above to take an `int` and a `char *[]`...

Comment: @vonbrand: there are guarantees for hosted implementations in C (C99 and C11 at least) and C++. `int main(void)` and `int main(int, char**)` (essentially) must be supported (with well defined parameter & return value semantics) by conforming hosted implementations. C++ has the limitation that main cannot be called recursively, C doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `main()` after 1 second to create some sort of loop to wait for a specified amount of time, you can use an *actual* loop! Try something like this:

```
checkTime(&getCheckTime);
while(*getFirstArgument != getCheckTime) {
    sleep(1);
    checkTime(&getCheckTime);
}

// Do something after the provided time
if(*getSecondArgument == 'r') {
    system("shutdown /r");
} else {
    system("shutdown /s"); 
}
```

Furthermore, I do not really understand what you are planning to do. So the snippet above will not likely fix your complete program.

Comment: This has the further, and important, advantage that it won't run out of stack space if the time described by the first argument is much later than the time when the program started. The recursive solution originally proposed would undoubtedly run out of stack space at some point.

Comment: @Veger, now I am learning C and I am trying to make a simple shutdowner, to understand how programming really works. Thank you for the answer, no more error after this fix, but anyway the program not work. Anyway, thank you for answer, I have to see why I can't shutdown the pc! :)